# Set an arrays keys value after creating an array

Tags: php

I'm trying to set an array key's value after I've created the array. I know this will, and this does give the error :

`Notice: Undefined variable: peter in C:\web\apache\htdocs\test\array.php on line 144 Peter is years old.`

```
$age=array("Peter"=>$ageVal);// Has to come first, since it's inside an include file.

$ageVal = 35; //Comes later.

echo "Peter is " . $age['Peter'] . " years old.";
```

But is there some way to do this just like this without changing the sequence? a) Array gets created first b) Array key's value is set later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by assigning the array value [by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php), although I would not recommend doing this.

This works (but I don't reccomend it):

```
$age=array("Peter" => &$ageVal);// Has to come first, since it's inside an include file.

$ageVal = 35; //Comes later.

echo "Peter is " . $age['Peter'] . " years old.";
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/KjtePn)

This is the way I recommend doing it instead:

```
$age = array(); // Comes first, since it's inside an include file.

$ageVal = 35; // Comes later.
$age['Peter'] = $ageVal; // Assigns a value to the 'Peter' key in $age

echo "Peter is " . $age['Peter'] . " years old.";
```

Comment: Your first approach is really neat. But why do you not recommend it? What might go wrong?

Comment: @jmenezes There are a few reasons. References are not common in PHP code, so other developer's may not be familiar with them. They can make the code really confusing and difficult to read (Everyone knows that `$ageVal = 35;` assigns `35` to `$ageVal`, nobody would expect it to also assign to `$age['Peter']`). They aren't true references (like C pointers) and a lot of programmers get them wrong and end up confused. I believe they are also often more slow than a normal assignment in PHP.

Comment: I see what you mean. I figured out the hard way ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can set two variables in one line.

```
$age['Peter'] = $ageVal = 35;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't initialise your array at the top.

```
$age=array();// Has to come first, since it's inside an include file.

$ageVal = 35; //Comes later.
$age['Peter'] = $ageval;  // Set the array element here.

echo "Peter is " . $age['Peter'] . " years old.";
```